# Please support to change date in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class EdidPickDate extends StatefulWidget {
EdidPickDate({
super.key,
this.onTap,
required this.hintText,
this.onChanged,
this.labelText,
 });

final void Function()? onTap;
final String? hintText;
Function(String)? onChanged;
final String? labelText;

@override
State<EdidPickDate> createState() => _EdidPickDateState();
}

class _EdidPickDateState extends State<EdidPickDate> {
```

final TextEditingController? _date = TextEditingController();
Function(String)? onChanged;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
child: TextFormField(
controller: _date,
decoration: InputDecoration(
icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today_outlined),
labelText: widget.labelText,
hintText: widget.hintText,
enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.greenAccent),
),
),
onTap: () async {
DateTime? pickeddate = await showDatePicker(
context: context,
initialDate: DateTime.now(),
firstDate: DateTime(1920),
lastDate: DateTime(2300));

```
      if (pickeddate != null) {
        setState(() {
        _date?.text = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(pickeddate);
          
        });
      }
    },
    onChanged: onChanged,
  ),
);
```

}
}

`
class edid_Person_Body extends StatefulWidget {
const edid_Person_Body({
Key? key,
required this.person,
}) : super(key: key);
final PersonModel person;

@override
State<edid_Person_Body> createState() => _edid_Person_BodyState();
}

class _edid_Person_BodyState extends State<edid_Person_Body> {
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

String? barthday,;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Form(
child: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
child: ListView(
children: [
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
child: Row(
children: [
Column(
children: [

```
        EdidPickDate(
          onChanged: (value) {
            barthday = value;
          },
          labelText: 'brithday',
          hintText: widget.person.barthday,
        ),
      

        CustomAddBotton(
          texet: 'eddid',
          onTap: () {
            
            widget.person.barthday = barthday ?? widget.person.barthday;
      

            widget.person.save();
            BlocProvider.of<PersonCubit>(context).fetchAllPerson();

            Navigator.pop(context);
            debugPrint("ok$barthday");
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onChanged` will be called only when the user enters by keyboard, so you can call `onChanged` on `onTap` date picked.

Also you have unassinged `onChanged` in `_EdidPickDateState`. So try with following code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class EdidPickDate extends StatefulWidget {
  EdidPickDate({
    super.key,
    this.onTap,
    required this.hintText,
    this.onChanged,
    this.labelText,
  });

  final void Function()? onTap;
  final String? hintText;
  Function(String)? onChanged;
  final String? labelText;

  @override
  State<EdidPickDate> createState() => _EdidPickDateState();
}

class _EdidPickDateState extends State<EdidPickDate> {
  final TextEditingController _date = TextEditingController();

  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _date,
        decoration: InputDecoration(icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today_outlined),
          labelText: widget.labelText,
          hintText: widget.hintText,
          enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.greenAccent),),),
        onTap: () async {
          DateTime? pickeddate = await showDatePicker(
              context: context, initialDate: DateTime.now(), firstDate: DateTime(1920), lastDate: DateTime(2300));

          if (pickeddate != null) {
            _date.text = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(pickeddate);
          }
          widget.onChanged?.call(_date.text);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```